# client_side_validations 'Cannot read property 'user[email]' of undefined'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, client-side-validation

So I am trying to get `client_side_validations` gem working and when I tab out of my email field, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user[email]' of undefined
```

This is my form helper:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => "send-with-ajax", :url => user_registration_path(resource), :validate => true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :id => "form-email", :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true}, :validate => true %>                
      <%= f.submit :label => "Submit", :value => "Sign Me Up!"  %>
      <div class="ajax-response"><%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
<% end %>
```

Which generates this HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" data-validate="true" id="new_user" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
     <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
     <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="9JdqaiushdauhsdioauhdoiuhNLSAVCGrc+PLJAQ=" />
     <input data-validate="true" id="form-email" input_html="{:autofocus=&gt;true}" name="user[email]" placeholder="your-email@address.com" size="30" type="email" />
     <input label="Submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign Me Up!" />
     <div class="ajax-response"></div>
</form>
```

**Edit 1:** Even when I change the form helper from `f.email_field :email`, to `f.text_field :email`...I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution, it seems that either `client_side_validations` or `devise` are altering the `id` of the form - which would break the JS validation.

So the solution is to enforce the `id` of the form, so my `form_for` helper now looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => "send-with-ajax", :url => user_registration_path(resource), :validate => true, :html => { :id => 'user_new' }) do |f| %>
```

I found this [solution here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/325).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following [#263 Client Side Validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations). This should help.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't cover that particular issue. I was following this Railscast when I came upon this error.